# Do Schengen visa authorities phone employers to verify employment? My boss received a call but the caller didn't identify himself

Tags: schengen

I applied for a Schengen visa in London a few days ago and my boss received a call from a withheld number yesterday, asking whether I work there.

Because of data protection, my boss asked the caller who he was before he spoke about whether I work there and any other questions.
The line was apparently bad and the caller disconnected without disclosing who he was. Tried again but disconnected after one ring.

Now I cannot think of anyone who would want to confirm my employment at this point.

Just wondering if it could be the Schengen visa processing consulate calling to ask about me?

Is this something that they do to verify the payslip and letter?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it *could* be, but Schengen country consulates *also* have data protection and privacy law to take into account, and they shouldn't be disclosing to your employer that you are applying for a visa.

If your visa application included a letter from your employer confirming your employment or your leave or anything else, the consulate could have been calling to confirm the authenticity of the letter.  A proper form for this purpose would be for the caller to identify her- or himself, to mention the letter from the company, and to ask to confirm its authenticity.  Only after that should there be any discussion of the letter's contents (for example, whether you are still employed at the company).

Given the description of the call, I suspect that it was something else, but I suppose it also could have been a poorly trained consular worker (or a well trained one working for a consulate with poorly conceived procedures).

Comment: Thank you for your message. As the caller disconnected before the verification was complete and then the next time, disconnected after one ring, I'm concerned how this will affect my application. I hope they don't reject it as a result.

Comment: Would it be worthwhile emailing the consulate? Although it's apparently the foreign ministry that handles the applications not the consulate here.

Comment: @Shell9 It's certainly reasonable to try to call the consulate to verify the authenticity of the call.  That could also help your application if the call was legitimate.

Comment: Thank you.The Consulate of Netherlands in London does not process the applications apparently. Apparently all applications are processed in the Netherlands by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs. There doesn't seem any way to contact the visa processing team but I'll try to ask the Consulate if they can advise anything.